# Changing ScrollReveal.js viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, viewport

I am wanting to use ScrollReveal.js (https://github.com/julianlloyd/scrollReveal.js) with Isotope on my project to animate objects in as the user scrolls, but the page has to have a fixed div that fits the whole viewport. This means that the page doesn't actually scroll, the user scrolls within the fixed div.

Im looking for a way to change the viewport that ScrollReveal references. Instead of tracking the scrolling of a page, it tracks the scrolling of a particular div.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

```
<main id="mainn">
        <div class="isotope">
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2 height2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2 height2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2 height2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2 height2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2 height2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2 height2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2 height2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2 height2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2 height2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2 height2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2 height2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2 height2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2 height2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2 height2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2 height2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2 height2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2 height2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2 height2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2 height2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2 height2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2 height2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2 height2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2 height2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2"></div>
            <div data-sr='scale up 20%' class="item width2 height2"></div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

Codepen here: http://codepen.io/grahammcuk/pen/ogBNdp

Comment: Your `id` is set to `mainn` which I assume is a typo… I changed it to `main` and put together a working demo. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

v2.3.2

The key is to specify a viewport in the constructor config object.

`window.sr = new scrollReveal({
  viewport: document.getElementById('main')
});`

Here is a working Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ByRxKG

---

**Update:** v3.0.0

The concept is the same, but it looks a little different:

`window.sr = ScrollReveal({
  container: document.getElementById('main')
});`

- Constructor is capitalized
- `viewport` —renamed—> `container`